# how to create 2D using two different array or single array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I want output like this:

```
items = [['red', 'blue', 'green'], ['small', 'medium', 'large']]
```

I have array item which has value:

```
items = ['red', 'blue', 'green','small', 'medium', 'large']
```

Comment: `array.flat()` end

Answer (score 0):

if mutation is not a problem, then you might remove initial array until you move them 3 by 3 into new one.

```
const items = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'small', 'medium', 'large'];

let itemList = [];

while (items.length > 0) {
    itemList.push(items.splice(0, 3))
}
```